# arara root file (compile the main file)

Tags: arara

The arara manual on page 21 bottom

> The directive context also features another special parameter named `files`
> which expects a non-empty list of file names as plain string values. For each
> element of this list, arara will replicate the current directive and point the ele-
> ment being iterated as current `reference` value (resolved to a proper absolute,
> canonical path of the file name).

( Important changes in the 5.x series ) at page 22 says:

> arara previously had the file name string reference as the `file` variable
> in the rule context. As of version 5.0, support for this variable has been
> dropped. Users should favour the `reference` variable instead, since it
> holds the absolute, canonical representation of the file name as a proper
> `File` object.

on page 14

> Our tool has two names reserved for internal use:
> `files` , and `reference` . Do not use them as argument identifiers!

and on page 16

> `reference`
> This variable holds the canonical, absolute path representation of
> the file name as a File object. This is useful if it’s necessary to
> know the hierarchical structure of a project. Since the reference
> is a Java object, we can use all methods available in the File class.

I have a file called `file1.tex` which is part of `main.tex`. In file1.tex I have `% arara: lualatex: { files: [ main.tex ] }` so if I compile file1.tex is actualy starting compile the main file.

**What I'm asking you:**
Since English is not my natural language I'm a little bit confused of the information and I need a clarification if my `% arara: ...` is actually getting the main file to be compiled and sees file1.tex as not being the main one, or I'm just lucky with `{file: [main.tex] }` because changing the command to:

`% arara: lualatex: { reference: [ main.tex ] }` I get the error:

> I read a directive (3) and found out that the key 'reference' was
> used. This key is reserved, so you cannot use it. But do not
> worry, this should be an easy fix. Just replace it by another
> name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two things here: `file` (removed in v5, note the singular) and `reference` are parameters arara passes into the rule and directive context. You can't change them. `files` on the other hand is a parameter you can set in the way you did; being reserved here just means you cannot call a parameter in an own rule `files`.

So to answer your question: You are absolutely correct to use `files` to specify your main file.

Nitpick: arara does not know the concept of a main file, it only does what you instruct it to do. Hence, you are actually just overwriting arara's default to act on `reference` by being more explicit and using `files`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!